SwiftUI application UI testing element name during Apple Sign-In
I am currently working on the UI Test for account deletion feature. Since I am only including Apple Auth with my app thru Firebase, reauth is required at account deletion. I am having trouble with the name of the elements in the screenshot. What are their names? I tried using tables.staticTexts["Share My Email"], but it is not the correct one.

